# How to create a JSONArray without a name in Delphi?

Tags: arrays, json, file, delphi

I have been searching the internet for a couple of days and have been trying out lots of things but I did not manage to create a JSONArray without a name yet.

Normally a JSONArray looks like this:

```
"MyArray" [

//content

]
```

But I need this:

```
[

//content

]
```

My JSON-File needs to look like this in the end:

```
[

    {

        "videos":"Hello.MOV",

        "render-status":"ready",

        "output":"test\\out1.mov"

    },

    {

        "videos":"123.MOV",

        "render-status":"ready",

        "output":"test\\out1.mov"

    },

]
```

By the way I am using Delphi 10.2.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Micha

Comment: Create an array as your root object. That's it.

Comment: You can define your array as a global variable or const too.

Comment: @AbdullahIlgaz I'm not sure what that has to do with the question at all... Global variables are highly discouraged in Delphi...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [JsonDataObjects](https://github.com/ahausladen/JsonDataObjects)

```
uses
  JsonDataObjects;

const
  JSON_ARRAY =
    '[{"videos":"Hello.MOV","render-status":"ready","output":"test\\out1.mov"},{"videos":"123.MOV","render-status":"ready","output":"test\\out1.mov"}]';

procedure TJsonTests.BuildArrayTest;
var
  A: TJsonArray;
  O: TJsonObject;
  V: string;
begin
  A := TJsonArray.Create;
  try
    O := A.AddObject;
    O.S['videos'] := 'Hello.MOV';
    O.S['render-status'] := 'ready';
    O.S['output'] := 'test\out1.mov';

    O := A.AddObject;
    O.S['videos'] := '123.MOV';
    O.S['render-status'] := 'ready';
    O.S['output'] := 'test\out1.mov';

    CheckEquals(2, A.Count);
    V:= A.ToJSON();
    CheckEquals(JSON_ARRAY, V);
  finally
    A.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TJsonTests.ParseArrayTest;
var
  A: TJsonArray;
  V: string;
begin
  A := TJsonArray.Create;
  try
    A.FromUtf8JSON(JSON_ARRAY);
    CheckEquals(2, A.Count);
    V:= A.ToJSON();
    CheckEquals(JSON_ARRAY, V);
  finally
    A.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Hi, this may sound like a silly question, but I'm gonna ask it anyways:
Why is 
"A.FromUtf8JSON(JSON_ARRAY)"=
"2" (as you expect it to be "2" in "CheckEquals(2, A.Count)")?

Comment: It is just a unit test code to validate the library routine, it should check that the array has 2 items...

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Stadard System.JSON objects in Delphi as well.

```
uses
  System.JSON;

function CreateArray: TJSONArray;
var
  LTempObject: TJSONOBject;
begin
  Result := TJSONArray.Create;

  LTempObject := TJSONOBject.Create;
  LTempObject.AddPair('videos', 'Hello.MOV');
  LTempObject.AddPair('render-status', 'ready');
  LTempObject.AddPair('output', 'test\out1.mov');
  Result.AddElement(LTempObject);

  LTempObject := TJSONOBject.Create;
  LTempObject.AddPair('videos', '123.MOV');
  LTempObject.AddPair('render-status', 'ready');
  LTempObject.AddPair('output', 'test\out1.mov');
  Result.AddElement(LTempObject);
end;
```

Use Like so:

```
var
  LJSON: TJSONArray;
begin
  LJSON := CreateArray;
  //Will give you exact string as above
  //without and formatting
  memo.Text := LJSON.ToJSON; 
end;
```